# IF when zero result from another Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Stored Procedure which contains an `Insert` statement on it.

```
create procedure Sp1
(@oName varchar(50), @Address varchar(100))
as
begin
     insert into Tb1(Name, Address)values(@oName, @Address)
end
```

From the above Stored Procedure, I want to have a condition from result of another Stored Procedure. With the following action:

```
select count(Branch) cBranch from Tb2 group by Branch
```

So, if `cBranch` is `zero`. Then `execute Sp1` else do nothing.

Need advice please. Really appreciated.

Comment: Create another stored proc that selects from branch, evaluates the result count, returns it if less then 1 else calls sp1? Where does the call for sp1 get its parameters from in that case? Why do you need to pass parameters not needed at all to a proc that does a select to eventually do an insert into a table that then returns a count of it? Simply return 0 as the count? and if you get a 0 count back, do the insert?

Comment: Sp1 need to be updated with Condition if zero result from 'let say' Sp2. Sp2 is to count the Branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NAME
AS
DECLARE @Cndtn INT
SELECT @Cndtn=COUNT(Branch) FROM Tb2 GROUP BY Branch

IF(@Cndtn>0)
BEGIN
EXEC Sp1 @oName,@Address
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 'Else Clause' --Add an another SP name
END
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot mate! Really appreciated. I've a clue now to update my Sp based on your answer. :)